# Plot integral expression

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

Trying to plot in Mathematica with an integral as the iterator

```
Plot[x, {Integrate[1/Sqrt[0.31*x + 0.68*x^4 + 0.01*x^2], x], 0, 10^7}]
```

But get the error that it the integral can't be used as an iterator. On the other hand if I try

```
Plot[Integrate[1/Sqrt[0.31*x + 0.68*x^4 + 0.01*x^2], x], {x, 0, 10^7}]
```

I get the 'invalid integration variable or limit' error.

Comment: You try to plot something like `Plot[x,{f[x],f0,f1}]`? That's only possible, I think,  if you know the `InverseFunction` of f:  `Plot[InverseFunction[f[x]],{f ,f0,f1}]`

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>   Plot[x, {Integrate[1/Sqrt[0.31*x + 0.68*x^4 + 0.01*x^2], x], 0, 10^7}]
> ```

This is not going to work, because  Plot has the form `Plot[f[x],{x,from,to}]` and so you need a symbol in `x` and not `Integrate` in there.

> ```
>    Plot[Integrate[1/Sqrt[0.31*x + 0.68*x^4 + 0.01*x^2], x], {x, 0, 10^7}]
> ```

For this one, you can make it to work like this

```
foo[to_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{x}, NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[0.31*x + 0.68*x^4 + 0.01*x^2], {x, 0, to}]];

Plot[foo[x], {x, 0, 10}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]